# How to build an rx poller that waits some interval AFTER the previous ajax promise resolves?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Been working on a few approaches to this. Basically, I don't want a poller that kicks off an ajax every 30 seconds from the start of polling -- I want a poller that kicks off requests 30 seconds AFTER the previous request returns. Plus, I want to work in some strategy around exponential back-off for failures.

Here's what I have so far (Rx4):

```
rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    var nextPoll = function(obs) {
      // the action function invoked below is what i'm passing in
      // to my poller service as any function which returns a promise
      // and must be invoked each loop due to fromPromise caching
      rx.Observable.fromPromise(action())
        .map(function (x){ return x.data; })
        .subscribe(function(d) {       
            // pass promise up to parent observable  
            observer.onNext(d);

            // reset interval in case previous call was an error
            interval = initInterval;   
            setTimeout(function(){ nextPoll(obs); }, interval);
        }, function(e) {
          // push interval higher (exponential backoff)
          interval = interval < maxInterval ? interval * 2 : maxInterval;
          setTimeout(function(){ nextPoll(obs); }, interval);

        });
    };
    nextPoll(observer);
});
```

For the most part, this does what I want. I don't like the use of setTimeout, but I can't seem to find a better Observable approach to this (other than a one-off interval/timer with another subscribe).

The other thing that I haven't been able to work into this is the ability to control whether the poller, when initially started, can start with a delay or fire immediately. For some uses, I will have just fetched the data prior to starting to poll, so I can let it wait the interval before firing for the first time. So far, I've only had luck with timer/delay that happens before the first ajax or between the ajax and providing it to subscribers, which doesn't work for me.

Would appreciate any thoughts on cleaning this in, both generally and in terms of getting rid of the setTimeout. And, if anyone has a way to kick off this poller with an optional delay, that would be tremendous! Thanks all!!

UPDATE: Finally got this working the way I envisioned. Here's what that looks like:

```
function computeInterval(error) {
  if (error) {
    // double until maximum interval on errors
    interval = interval < maxInterval ? interval * 2 : maxInterval;
  } else {
    // anytime the poller succeeds, make sure we've reset to
    // default interval.. this also allows the initInterval to 
    // change while the poller is running
    interval = initInterval;
  }
  return interval;
}

poller$ = rx.Observable.fromPromise(function(){ return _this.action(); })
  .retryWhen(function(errors){
    return errors.scan(function(acc, x) { return acc + x; }, 0)
      .flatMap(function(x){ 
        return rx.Observable.timer(computeInterval(true));
      });
  })
  .repeatWhen(function(notification){
    return notification
      .scan(function(acc, x) { return acc + x; }, 0)
      .flatMap(function(x){ 
        return rx.Observable.timer(computeInterval());
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just gave it some quick thinking, so it will have to be tested, but hopefully it gets you on a valuable track:

```
var action; // your action function
Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
    function executeAction(action) {
        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(action()).materialize();
    }

    function computeDelay(){
        // put your exponential delaying logic here
    }

    executeAction()
        .expand(function (x) {
            return Rx.Observable.return({})
                .delay(computeDelay())
                .flatMap(function(){return executeAction(action);})
        })
        .subscribe(function(notification){
             if (notification.kind === "N") {
               observer.onNext(notification.value.data);
             } else if (notification.kind === "E") {
               console.log("error:", notification.error.message);
             }
        });
});
```

In short, the idea is to use the `expand` operator for the looping, and the `delay` operator for the delaying. Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md). Erros are managed using the `materialize` operator and the notification mechanism (this avoid abruptly terminating your polling stream in case of error returned by the promise).

Comment: Hey, so I think you're right about using expand. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on this inner loop not running without a subscribe after the .expand. Obviously, the ajax call happens once, but the expand never picks it up without executeAction.expand().subscribe().  ALSO, the loop quits if the promise errors. Previously, using a subscribe in here, I was able to keep it going even on error condition.

Comment: Yes sorry you have to subscribe, there is no way around it (except using a subject, but I don't see the issue with subscribing - what problem is it bringing to you?). Let me think about error management later. I updated the code sample by the way.

Comment: There are several solutions to handle error. I gave you one of them here which uses the `materialize` operator. You could also use the `catch` operator to catch the error and pass an error code or object down the stream. You can have a look at the issue here for a similar problem and its solution : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/829

Comment: Thanks so much for these ideas. What about retryWhen? It seems like that is suited to something like this. (sorry, new to Rx.. it's a lot to absorb!)

Comment: retryWhen can be tricky to use, so make sure you know how to use it. In your case you are polling so you are already retrying right?

Comment: Your question made me think about `repeatWhen` operator so I added another answer to my first answer. Have a look, maybe it is simpler. You can deal with error the same way than here by materializing the stream.

Answer (score 2):

I add another answer using another technique which can be useful and/or maybe simpler. It is based on the `repeatWhen` operator. As the [documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/repeatwhen.md) explains, it allows you to repeat subscription to an observable till you signal the end of the repetition indicating normal completion or an error.

```
var action; // your action function
Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
    function executeAction(action) {
        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(action());
    }

    function computeDelay(){
        // put your exponential delaying logic here
    }

executeAction()
  .repeatWhen(function(notification){
    return Rx.Observable.return({}).delay(computeDelay());
  })
  .subscribe(function(x){
    observer.onNext(x.data);
  })
});
```

There is a [terrific article](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/) here explaining `repeatWhen` and `retryWhen` better than the official documentation does (it is for RxJava but it applies to Rxjs with some minor modifications). It also gives an example of exactly what you want to achieve (exponential delayed repeating).

Comment: Hmm.. not quite getting there, but this has been helpful for sure. I'll post something on here when I finally settle on my solution. Thanks, again!

Comment: what do you mean by not getting there? And there I was hoping this would be a simpler solution.

Comment: I just updated my initial post with what I needed to do to really get this working right. Thanks for all your help.