# Convert infinite async callback sequence to Observable sequence?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Let's say I have the following asynchronous callback-based "infinite" sequence, which I cancel after some time:

```
'use strict';

const timers = require('timers');

let cancelled = false;

function asyncOperation(callback) {
  const delayMsec = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
  console.log(`Taking ${delayMsec}msec to process...`);
  timers.setTimeout(callback, delayMsec, null, delayMsec);
}

function cancellableSequence(callback) {
  asyncOperation((error, processTime) => {
    console.log('Did stuff');
    if (!cancelled) {
      process.nextTick(() => { cancellableSequence(callback); });
    } else {
      callback(null, processTime);
    }
  });
}

cancellableSequence((error, lastProcessTime) => {
  console.log('Cancelled');
});

timers.setTimeout(() => { cancelled = true; }, 0);
```

The `asyncOperation` will execute and call back at least once, and the cancellation message will not display immediately, but rather after `asyncOperation` is complete.  The number of calls to `asyncOperation` depends on the internal `delayMsec` value and the delay argument passed to `setTimeout()` at the end (an attempt to show that these are variable).

I'm starting to learn RxJS5, and thought it might be possible to convert this into an Observable sequence ("oooh, an Observable subscription can be unsubscribe()d - that looks neat!").

However, my attempts at turning `cancellableSequence` into an ES6 generator (how else to make infinite?) yielding `Observable.bindNodeCallback(asyncOperation)()` resulted in immediate yields, which in my case is undesired behavior.

I cannot use `Observable.delay()` or `Observable.timer()`, as I do not have a known, consistent interval.  (The Math.random(...) in `asyncOperation` was an attempt to indicate that I as the caller do not control the timing, and the callback happens "some unknown time later.")

My failed attempt:

```
'use strict';

const timers = require('timers');
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');

function asyncOperation(callback) {
  const delayMsec = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
  console.log(`Taking ${delayMsec}msec to process...`);
  timers.setTimeout(callback, delayMsec, null, delayMsec);
}

const operationAsObservable = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(asyncOperation);
function* generator() {
  while (true) {
    console.log('Yielding...');
    yield operationAsObservable();
  }
}

Rx.Observable.from(generator()).take(2).mergeMap(x => x).subscribe(
  x => console.log(`Process took: ${x}msec`),
  e => console.log(`Error: ${e}`),
  c => console.log('Complete')
)
```

Which results is the output:

```
Yielding...
Taking 2698msec to process...
Yielding...
Taking 2240msec to process...
Process took: 2240msec
Process took: 2698msec
Complete
```

The yields occur right away.  The `Process took: xxx` output occurs when you'd expect (after 2240 and 2698ms, respectively).

(In all fairness, the reason I care about the delay in between yields is that `asyncOperation()` here is in reality a rate-limiting token bucket library which controls the rate of asynchronous callbacks - an implementation which I'd like to retain.)

As an aside, I attempted to replace `take(2)` with a delayed cancellation, but that never occurred:

```
const subscription = Rx.Observable.from(generator()).mergeMap(x => x).subscribe(
  x => console.log(`Process took: ${x}msec`),
  e => console.log(`Error: ${e}`),
  c => console.log('Complete')
)

console.log('Never gets here?');
timers.setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Cancelling...');
  subscription.unsubscribe();
}, 0);
```

Can what I'm attempting be accomplished with a cancellable subscription via RxJS?  (I can see other approaches, such as `process.exec('node', ...)` to run `asyncOperation()` as a separate process, giving me the ability to `process.kill(..)`, etc., but let's not go there...).

Is my initial callback-based implementation the suggested way to implement a cancellable sequence?

UPDATED SOLUTION:

See my reply comment to @user3743222's answer below.  Here's what I ended up with (replace ES6 generator with `Observable.expand()`):

```
'use strict';

const timers = require('timers');
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');

function asyncOperation(callback) {
  const delayMsec = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
  console.log(`Taking ${delayMsec}msec to process...`);
  timers.setTimeout(callback, delayMsec, null, delayMsec);
}

const operationAsObservable = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(asyncOperation);

const subscription = Rx.Observable
  .defer(operationAsObservable)
  .expand(x => operationAsObservable())
  .subscribe(
    x => console.log(`Process took: ${x}msec`),
    e => console.log(`Error: ${e}`),
    c => console.log('Complete')
  );

subscription.add(() => {
  console.log('Cancelled');
});

timers.setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Cancelling...');
  subscription.unsubscribe();
}, 0);
```

UPDATED SOLUTION 2:

Here's what I came up with for the alternate RxJS4 `repeatWhen()` approach:

```
'use strict';

const timers = require('timers');
const Rx = require('rx');

function asyncOperation(callback) {
  const delayMsec = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
  console.log(`Taking ${delayMsec}msec to process...`);
  timers.setTimeout(callback, delayMsec, null, delayMsec);
}

const operationAsObservable = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(asyncOperation);

const subscription = Rx.Observable
  .defer(operationAsObservable)
  .repeatWhen(x => x.takeWhile(y => true))
  .subscribe(
    x => console.log(`Process took: ${x}msec`),
    e => console.log(`Error: ${e}`),
    c => console.log('Complete')
  );

timers.setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Cancelling...');
  subscription.dispose();
}, 10000);
```

Comment: What is issue with first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be repeating an action every time it finishes. That looks like a good use case for `expand` or `repeatWhen`.

Typically, that would be something like :

```
Rx.Observable.just(false).expand(_ => {  
  return cancelled ? Rx.Observable.empty() : Rx.Observable.fromCallback(asyncAction)
})
```

You put `cancelled` to true at any point of time and when the current action finishes, it stops the loop. Haven't tested it so I would be interested to know if that worked in the end.

You can have a look at similar questions about polling:

- [How to build an rx poller that waits some interval AFTER the previous ajax promise resolves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856397/how-to-build-an-rx-poller-that-waits-some-interval-after-the-previous-ajax-promi)

Documentation:

- [[fromCallback]](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromcallback.md)
- [[expand]](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md)

Documentation links are for Rxjs 4 but there should not be much changes vs v5

Comment: Using Observable.timer() or Observable.delay() (the key to the solution in your provided URL) were not what I wanted, as they move the timing to the subscriber/caller, and I'm dealing with `asyncOperation` which cannot change (it imposes the timing).

However, Observable.expand() definitely gives me what I want.  I'll update my post to show my final solution.  Thanks!

Comment: There are two answers in the link I posted. One with `repeatWhen`, one with `expand`. Have a closer look, you probably read the question only. Happy that you solved your issue anyways.

Comment: I'm not following.  I read the entire thread, and that first answer using `repeatWhen()` internally uses `delay()`.  In the context of that question, my delay would happen internal to the execution of the `action` method.

Comment: Update: figured the `repeatWhen()` approach out and added to the question.  Is there an RxJS5 equivalent?  The migration doc shows that hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: well then I guess there is no easy way to replicate it. Go with `expand`. I actually prefer it for asynchronous looping over `repeatWhen`.