# Chain Observable emissions?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have two independent Observables that I'd like to couple in such a manner that every time the first emits a value, it causes the second to emit a value.

In this scenario, the first Observable is an infinite sequence based on an async Node.js-style method with variable callback timing (no usage of `delay` or `timer` allowed).  The second Observable is a finite sequence of independent values.

Perhaps a diagram can express what I'm looking for:

```
I: ---A--D-----Q-G---B-> (I is infinite)
F: -3512-|->             (F is finite)
O: ---3--5-----1-2-|->   (O is finite)
```

The output sequence (O) is finite with the values from (F), based on the timing of (I).

Here's (I):

```
// I'm stuck with this, it cannot change...
function asyncOperation(callback) {
  const delayMsec = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  timers.setTimeout(callback, delayMsec, null, delayMsec);
}

const callbackObservable = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(asyncOperation);

const infiniteCallbackSequence = Rx.Observable
  .defer(callbackObservable)
  .expand(x => callbackObservable());
```

And for simplicity, here's (F):

```
const finiteSequence = Rx.Observable.from([3, 5, 1, 2]);
```

(This build upon a previous Question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262208/convert-infinite-async-callback-sequence-to-observable-sequence).)

I don't understand things well enough to make `combine*`, `merge*`, or `*map` work to generate what I want -- assuming they can.  It seems like I want `take(1)` on (I) each time (O) emits.

How do I get the behavior described?

Comment: the `|` does not seem to match an event from `I`, is it normal?

Comment: I apologize, @njzk2.  Those pipe symbols merely represent "end of sequence".  I think the marble diagrams on the main RxJS documentation use 'X' to denote such, but that looked more confusing in my ASCII diagram above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [`Observable.zip`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md) work for your usecase?

```
const Rx = require('rxjs');
const timers = require('timers');

const finite = Rx.Observable.from([3, 5, 1, 2]);

// I'm stuck with this, it cannot change...
function asyncOperation(callback) {
  const delayMsec = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  timers.setTimeout(callback, delayMsec, null, delayMsec);
}

const callbackObservable = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(asyncOperation);

const infiniteCallbackSequence = Rx
  .Observable
  .defer(callbackObservable)
  .expand(x => callbackObservable());

const combined = Rx.Observable.zip(
  finite,
  infiniteCallbackSequence
).forEach(v => console.log(v));
```

running on node 6:

```
➜ $ node test.js
[ 3, 816 ]
[ 5, 297 ]
[ 1, 95 ]
[ 2, 677 ]
➜ $
```